# C++ 'map' number ranges

Tags: c++, c

Is there a better way in C or C++, or just mathematically in general, to map ratios of numbers while preserving or rounding data?

> Take the following example

```
double cdp = 17000.0;    
float integ = 30000.0 / 255;
int val = cdp / integ;

color = color + RGB(val, val, val);
```

Here I want to map a range of numbers [0, 30000] to a value [0, 255]

Comment: What's wrong in the way given snippet does it?

Comment: changing question from "good way" to "better way"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply by 255 then divide by 30000. Use an integer format that can hold the product of your two range limits, 30000*255 or 7.65 million. This avoids the precision issues with intermediate floating point values.

Comment: And possibly add a bias (offset), because integer division truncates rather than rounding.  e.g. `val = (cdp * 255 + 15000) / 30000;`

Answer (score 9):

You can use a simple linear interpolation to do it, if I'm understanding correctly. It would work like this:

```
x = (inValue - minInRange) / (maxInRange - minInRange);
result = minOutRange + (maxOutRange - minOutRange) * x
```

where inValue is the number out of 30,000 in your example. minInRange = 0, maxInRange = 30,000, minOutRange = 0, maxOutRange = 255.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I just came across this and found out you're actually missing subtracting minInRange from inValue before calculating x when it isn't 0, the full formula should look like `result = minOutRange + (in - minInRange) * OutSize / InSize` where OutSize and InSize are `maxOutRange - minOutRange` and `maxInRange - minInRange`, respectively

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round to the nearest value rather than truncate any fractional component, then you have to do this:

```
double prod = cpd * 255; //double is big enough to hold the product without loss of precision
val = (int)(prod / 30000 + 0.5); //Adding 0.5 turns truncation into rounding.
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs templated version of @user1118321 proposed

```
    template<typename T>
    struct interpolation{
      T min_in, max_in, min_out, max_out;
      interpolation(T min_in_, T max_in_, T min_out_, T max_out_): min_in(min_in_), max_in(max_in_), min_out(min_out_), max_out(max_out_){
      }
    };

    template<typename T, typename interpolate_type>
    T map_range_1d(T value, interpolate_type interp_type){
        double x = (value - interp_type.min_in) / (interp_type.max_in - interp_type.min_in);
        return interp_type.min_out + (interp_type.max_out - interp_type.min_out) * x;    
    }

    template<typename T, typename interpolate_type>
    std::pair<T,T> map_range_2d(T value_x, T value_y, interpolate_type interp_type_x, interpolate_type interp_type_y){
        std::pair<T,T> mapped_values = {map_range_1d(value_x, interp_type_x), map_range_1d(value_y, interp_type_y)}; 
        return mapped_values; 
    }

    typedef interpolation<double> interp1d;
    constexpr auto map_range2d = &map_range_2d<double, interp1d>;
    constexpr auto map_range1d = &map_range_1d<double, interp1d>;
```

How to use it

```
        interp1d x_range(min_x_in, max_x_in, min_x_out, max_x_out);
        double index_local = map_range1d(456, x_range);
```